# Filter not working on Tablesorter 2.17.8 > probably my bad

Tags: tablesorter

Been working on getting the UITheme Widget (Bootstrap v3.x) version going to behave exactly the same as this. https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html.

Paging & sorting are working fine. When I click on a search box in the 2nd row to type something, for some strange reason, the sort feature fires & as I type nothing happens.

Ive checked over the head code to compare with the documentation & they are the same. When I inspect with Chrome, I can see an additional class of table sorter-header-inner yet this is not in the code of the 2nd row (search row)

An example page with my code can be found [here](http://utilisedev01.azurewebsites.net/en-au/my-dashboard/manage-receipts)

It could very well be that I have not added a css file or something. Ive searched the files that come with the download above & can't seem to find any additional files related to a filter widget.

Would really appreciate some assistance getting this nailed.

Thanks in advance.

Todd

Comment: Try removing the `"tablesorter-filter-row"` row from the HTML. Also please use the most up-to-date version of tablesorter.. it is currently v2.27.6.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mottie, Little bit embarrassing & a trap for new players but I found myself inspecting elements & copying that code directly into the header. not following your documentation to the letter & simply having say English and letting all the magic happen behind the scenes... I'm probably not the first person to have tried this but hope other newbies benefit from me sharing